# What are primary uses and stat advantages of each character?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In terms of base stats, what is the primary value of each team member (which one has the highest stats in what areas)?  What does this mean in terms of use? (partial to magic vs might etc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The system is actually quite complex, so if you want a full understanding of it, I'm just going to refer you to [TFergusson's Party Mechanics Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/36775), section 1.4 has all the details.

If you just want a general idea though, here's a table that I pulled out of that guide, summing up each character's "grade" in each stat. The numbers range from 0-29, and lower numbers represent larger gains.

```
             Str   Vit   Mag   Spr   Dex
=================================================
     Cloud     1     6     3     4    26
    Barret     5     2    18    14    29
      Tifa     6    18    16     9    25
     Aeris    23    20     0     1    28
       Red    12    11    13     9    23
    Yuffie    16    19    11    10    24
 Cait Sith    19    22     6     4    28
   Vincent    21    22     6     4    28
       Cid    11     7    17    15    27
=================================================
```

Comment: wow, never knew cait sith had decent magic stat, all these recent ff7 questions makes me want to go back and play it again

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I remember off of the top of my head:

```
 Cloud - Balanced, good at both
 Barret - Physical
 Tifa - Physical
 Aeris - Magical
 Red 13 - Balanced (His magic is quite good, don't overlook that)
 Cait Sith - Magical (pretty bad overall though)
 Cid - Physical
 Yuffie - Physical
 Vincent Valentine - Magical
```

I don't quite remember the affinity in terms of stats, but I do remember Yuffie always had the best luck.

If you want to grind, there are ways to get sources near the end game to boost everyone up to max stats so at that point it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I was really looking for stat specifics at a set level (before they are maxed).  For example at level 14 Tifa may have 16 strength and 14 vitality where as Barret may have 18 strength 13 vitality.  I know it cant feasibly be answered through memory, just curious if someone had raw statistics.

Comment: trying to experience the game at a level I never have before :)