# Why is Vincent's strength stat/attack damage so low?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm replaying Final Fantasy VII since it's re-release for the PC.

Currently my party consists of Cloud, Red XIII and Vincent.

I have all their ultimate weapons and they're all currently level 63.

I've noticed that Cloud and Red's strength stats are around 98 and 76 respectively, yet Vincent is at 49.

As a result of this, Vincent's attack damage is pretty low when compared with Cloud and Red's (around 600 per hit, vs. 1500-2000 from the others).

Is there much I can do to bring Vincent's attack up? Where can I find more power sources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are primary uses and stat advantages of each character?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/what-are-primary-uses-and-stat-advantages-of-each-character)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a few things to take into account. Vincent's is what you could consider a magic user. His stats lean towards Magic, as a result, you probably want to equip strong green or red materia on him.

```
HP:        Very Low (-5.2%)   
MP:        High ( 4.6%)       
Strength:  Very Low (-11%)    
Vitality:  Low (-9.1%)        
Magic:     Above Avg ( 2.8%)  
Spirit:    Above Avg ( 4%)  
Dexterity: Very Low (-10.1%)  
Luck:      Below Avg (-3.9%)
```

You mention that you have Vincent's ultimate weapon, which is Death Penalty. This gun's power increases every time Vincent kills an enemy, using [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/36775) formula:

```
Power = [Power * [Vincent's Kills / 128] / 16] + 10
```

So eventually, he could become really strong if you put some effort into it.

Additionally, there is a well known glitch that causes Vincent to kill enemies with one shot, provided the Death Penalty's power has been boosted to an extreme value. More information can be found [here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Penalty_Glitch#Final_Fantasy_VII).